# Element is not clickable at point ... with selenium 2 and WebDriver

Tags: selenium

today I searched a lot and found lots of information, but nothing helped.
I use selenium-java-2.53.1 and FF47 and face the following problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (779.5, 12.199996948242188). Other element would receive the click: <header class="header"></header>
Command duration or timeout: 106 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
System info: host: 'spa-PC', ip: '192.168.5.2', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_74'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=47.0.1, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: c897bef8-b708-45f3-a991-5cf8971939c8
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:85)
```

**It happens when I running this code:**

```
WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='show show-hide-accounts-button']"));
elementToClick.click();
```

**And use this part of HTML:**

```html
<div class="trader-wrapper">
<a class="avatar-frame-small" href="/bg/traders/5d2f970c-56e9-4ca1-99de-13ecb266bc82">
<span class="flag flag-lt" title="Литва"></span>
<a class="profile-link" href="/bg/traders/5d2f970c-56e9-4ca1-99de-13ecb266bc82">
<div class="trader-current-time">
<div class="accounts-summary">
<button class="follow-trader-ribbon" title="Start receiving trading activity updates from this Trader" data-user-name="Justinas Miezis" data-follow="53121">Follow </button>
<table class="trader-info">
<div class="gain-chart-wrapper trader">
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="show show-hide-accounts-button">Show account</div>
<div class="angled-separator top">
<div class="trader-accounts">
<div class="angled-separator bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Does somebody have workaround for this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which element is at point `779, 12` ?

Comment: This one: <div class="show show-hide-accounts-button">Show account</div>